# task distribution in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, task

My goal is to use hadoop for **task distribution** of an embarrassingly parallel problem, but with computationally expensive tasks.

Each task is typically a sequence of dependent byte code to be executed on a specific VM. The idea is to run this byte code in parallel where each mapper will behave as an independent VM. The reduce phase will be used for communication and merging purposes -- always through a VM --. Data will be shared among different nodes using a distributed-cache.

Hope I was clear til now.

**Here comes the problem:**

1. The input to my Map-Reduce problem is a byte code file with at most 1Mb of size, As far as I know Hadoop is not well suited for that.
2. It is up to me to split my ( super small ) file in order to guarantee load balancing. The splits are not supposed to have the same size, but +/- the same complexity.
3. The complexity of my tasks comes from the amount of data it is processing, which might be of order of several Gbs.

**Here comes the questions**

1. Might hadoop (Map-reduce in general) be configured to run well in such circumstances ?
2. Is it possible to configure the way we  define Splits to be more workload-centric and not size-centric ?

Thank you guys in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: Are you sure hadoop is the way to go?

Comment: the choice of a Map-reduce execution model is encouraged by the fact that sequentially we execute two separate steps. 

In a first time we create tuples in an independent way (kind of map), afterwards we setup relationships between these elements (kind of reduce).

Honestly, I am not so sure! The more I read about Hadoop, the less I'm sure about it. 
Is there a better model well suited for that than Map-reduce ?